# Didn't find cxLookUpComboBox.Properties.ItemHeight?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, vcl

I want to modify the default **height** of **items** in DevExpress VCL **cxLookUpComboBox**,
like we do with cxComboBox items (cxComboBox.Properties.ItemHeight).

Answer (score 3):

(almost literally) from the [DevExpress Q&A](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T663528/cxcombobox-and-cxlookupcombobox)

> The TcxComboBox and TcxLookupComboBox controls are very different.
>   TcxComboBox displays a simple List Box control as its dropdown
>   control, but TcxLookupComboBox contains a grid control with multiple
>   columns.
>
> If you wish to have more control over the Lookup Combobox appearance,
>   consider using its advanced version - TcxExtLookupComboBox. This
>   control displays a regular TcxGrid's data-aware view as its lookup
>   list, so you can use properties like `OptionsView.DataRowHeight` to
>   set up required dimensions.